# Send beacon information only once when detected

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am using AndroidBeaconLibrary reference program but having a small problem.

Created a global boolean variable to detect if is first time running part of the code:

```
boolean first_time;
```

In the onCreate I make it to be false:

```
first_time = false;
```

After when beacon is detected I change it value to true.

```
@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    if (monitoringActivity != null) {
        monitoringActivity.logToDisplay("I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);

        if ((state == 1)&&(first_time == false)) {
            //insert beacon data to server.
            first_time = true;
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                        Log.i("TEST", "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");

                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
        }
    }
```

Even though changing boolean value everytime it checks in the if command if it is true or not it is false, so everytime the message is displayed at Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
   if (state == 1) {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0 && first_time == false) {
                    //insert beacon data to server.
                    first_time = true;
                    Log.i("TEST", "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");

                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
```